# How to access an existing Hive table in Kubernetes POD

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

I am new to Kubernetes and we are trying to move an existing application to Kubernetes cluster.

This application is basically an ETL system which involves data warehouse, tables, DB and transformation of data.

In the process, we have created a POD that creates a Hive DB, table and inserted some data in it. We have done it through Spark.

Now we have created another POD that should read the data from the tables created by previous POD but it simply doesn't recognize the DB/table. It says the 'Database doesn't exist'.

So what do I have to do so that the table created in first POD should be visible by 2nd POD?

The idea was that we create 2 tables by first POD and then join it with some other table to insert data into a 3rd table but it's not working.